# Prolog compound terms

Tags: prolog

I hate to ask basic questions here, but, it seems, good manuals on Prolog are hard to find.

I have two terms:

```
woman(alice).
woman(janice).
```

Now, I want to make the following compound term:

```
sisters(woman(X), woman(Y)).
```

When I run the query sisters(X,Y), I get this mumbo jumbo:
    X = woman(_G2215),
    Y = woman(_G2217)

In fact, everything satisfies it.

```
sisters(woman(david), woman(xxxxxx))
```

is also true.

Why doesn't it work the intended way? It seems, prolog never looks at the first 2 terms.

I know I should make it

```
sisters(X, Y) :- woman(X), woman(Y), X \= Y
```

but I want to know why the first way doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To elaborate on Paulo's answer...

You have established the following facts:

```
woman(alice).    % 'alice' is a woman
woman(janice).   % 'janice' is a woman
sisters(woman(X), woman(Y)).   % woman(X) is a sister of woman(Y) for ANY X and Y
```

So you can see, for reasons Paulo points out about compound terms and that Prolog doesn't *recursively* query them, you're already headed in a direction you did not intend. In this context, you have stated a fact, `sisters(woman(X), woman(Y))` with two independent, uninstantiated variables. Since they are variables, and you don't have any `sisters/2` clause to constrain their values, they can be anything.

So for the following query:

```
sisters(X, Y).
```

Prolog looks at your facts and predicates for a match and finds, `sisters(woman(X), woman(Y))`. The logical answer is, therefore:

```
X = woman(_G2215)
Y = woman(_G2217)
```

This just says it is true for these values of `X` and `Y` where `_G2215` and `_G2217` are arbitrary variables. Any value of these would be true based upon the rules and facts you have stated. In particular that means that this is true:

```
sisters(woman(david), woman(xxxxxx))
```

Because `X` could be `david` and `Y` could be `xxxxxx` and it would be true, since your fact says:

```
sisters(woman(X), woman(Y)).
```

You could introduce a rule:

```
sisters(woman(X), woman(Y)) :- woman(X), woman(Y), X \= Y.
```

And then you'd start getting sensible answers to the query, `sisters(X, Y)`:

```
X = woman(alice)
Y = woman(janice)
```

Or more simply, as you have:

```
sisters(X, Y) :- woman(X), woman(Y), X \= Y.
```

With result:

```
X = alice
Y = janice
```

Answer (score 1):

In the case of the clause:

```
sisters(woman(X), woman(Y)).
```

the arguments are the terms `women/1`, **not** calls to the `women/1` predicate. Note that Prolog is not a functional language.